# How to change the size of fractions

Tags: fractions

Here's the code for the query:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[
\Longrightarrow \frac{\displaystyle \partial v^*}{\partial \gamma} = \frac{\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \gamma}}{\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial v^*} - \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial v^*}}.
\]
\end{document}
```

The fractions that appear in the numerator and the denominator on the right and left hand sides are smaller in size. How can I make them comparable in size to the one on the left side, which is of normal size?

Comment: Use `\dfrac`. Note `\ displaystyle` is not needed. You also might consider in intermediate size (~80 % of `\displaystyle`) with `\mfrac` from `nccmath`.

Comment: @Bernard - The equation is in displaymath-mode by default. Using `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` for the "outer" `\frac` macros would have no effect.

Comment: @Mico: I meant for the ‘inner’  fractions, since these were the O.P.'s problem